# Add tested pictures to Picture Hub on Windows Phone Emulator

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to add some tested picture files to People Hub on emulator, is there have a easy way to do that?

Comment: Picture hub or People hub? Either way, easiest is probably to save from web via IE.

Comment: Oh, sorry, it's Picture hub, and moreover, you can't use IE on emulator. :(

Comment: Really? I do it quite frequently.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a blog post that explains [how to add test images to the Windows Phone emulator](http://www.softwareisinthedetails.com/2012/11/add-test-images-on-windows-phone-emulator.html)